# How GMFBridge can be used in two independed processes?

Tags: ipc, directshow

How GMFBridge can be used in two independent processes?

So, usually we have two graphs in the same app can can easily bridge them together.

Any ideas how to do that in two apps - one app is "renderer", second is the "source"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter graphs don't do any interprocess communication for you, they are all supposed to live within a process. It is up to you to implement all `IPC` you need to sync the graphs.